# Search for multiple spaces in all list records

Tags: c#, linq

I am learning different options. Currently I have a list where I am performing several checks. One of them is searching for multiple spaces. If such a cases has been found whole row should go to list `MultipleSapces`.

```
    var MultipleSapces = list.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(i => new { i.NAME, i.MODEL, i.NAMEB, i.POSTADR }) // what columns to look?
        .GroupBy(dr => dr.NAME)                           // Not needed?
        .Where(gr => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gr))      // This is probably wrong?
        .SelectMany(g => g)                               // select whole row
        .ToList();
```

Here is netfiddle for testing: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WQ9nvE

As you can see `Fi  at` and `SE   0` has multiple spaces. So these rows should be in `MultipleSapces`. One space is allowed, more than 1 is not allowed.

Comment: `Where(gr => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gr))` -> `Where(gr => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gr.Key))`

Comment: `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gr)` this will not compile, use `gr.Key` instead. Could you please explain the point with spaces, what it the problem with your code?

Comment: Well if you have to find if a string has at least 2 consecutive space you can use simple regex like `( {2})` or `(\s{2})`. (The parentesisare here for markdown format for code near space you can remove them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to check if  a string has at least 2 consecutive space you can use simple regex like:
 `@" {2}"` or `@"\s{2}"`.

```
string pattern = @" {2}";   

var MultipleSapces = list.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(i => new { i.NAME, i.MODEL, i.NAMEB, i.POSTADR }) 
    .Where(x => Regex.IsMatch(x.NAME, pattern)  ||  Regex.IsMatch(x.NAMEB, pattern) )
    .ToList();
```

[LiveDemo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HHfz2C)

Comment: Thank you! Now I got it! I was a little bit confused how to use regex inside linq query. 
I just need to cover all columns in regex match now.